# vba for each loop with multiple if

Tags: vba, if-statement, foreach

I want to run a vba app to find the emails in this mailbox and give me the total number for each date from the last three days. The folder is correct and I can see the next mailitem. The main problem I am having is that I want the for each to end after it gets to the fourth day.  I am getting compile errors at the end of the foreach and nested if statements. Do I need to have Next anywhere if it's a for each?

```
Sub NonTicketEmailsCount()

Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim EmailCount As Integer
Dim MailItem
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

On Error Resume Next
Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("Mailbox - IT Support Center").Folders("Non ticket related emails")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
MsgBox "No such folder."
Exit Sub
End If

EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count

Dim dateStr As String
Dim dict As Object
Dim msg As String
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
' Determine date of each message:
For Each MailItem In objFolder.Items
     rt = MailItem.ReceivedTime 'getting received time for each mailitem
     nrt = Format(rt, "M/ d/ yyyy") 'formatting the received time to match value of datevalue keyword
     If DateValue(nrt) = Empty Then
        NonTicket0 = NonTicket0 + 1
     ElseIf DateValue(Date - 1) = DateValue(nrt) Then
        NonTicket1 = NonTicket1 + 1
     ElseIf DateValue(Date - 2) = DateValue(nrt) Then
        NonTicket2 = NonTicket2 + 1
     ElseIf DateValue(Date - 3) = DateValue(nrt) Then
        NonTicket3 = NonTicket3 + 1
     ElseIf DateValue(Date - 4) = DateValue(nrt) Then
        Exit For

    End If

msg = "Total NonTicket emails in the folder: " & EmailCount & vbNewLine _
& NonTicket1 & " = NonTicket Emails on " & Date - 1 & vbNewLine _
& NonTicket2 & " = NonTicket Emails on " & Date - 2 & vbNewLine _
& NonTicket3 & " = NonTicket Emails on " & Date - 3 & vbNewLine _

MsgBox "Number of emails in the folder: " & EmailCount & vbNewLine _
& "NonTicket Emails Yesterday: " & NonTicket1 & vbNewLine _
& "NonTicket Emails Yesterday: " & NonTicket2 & vbNewLine _
& "NonTicket Emails Yesterday: " & NonTicket3


'Send Mail
Set OutApp = CreateObject("outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(o)
With OutMail
.Subject = "Non Ticket Emails"
.To = "kylesparmark@glissondo.com; meisnert@glissondo.com"
.Body = msg
.Display
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objnSpace = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `NEXT` statement to close your `FOR EACH` loop:

```
For Each MailItem In objFolder.Items
     rt = MailItem.ReceivedTime 'getting received time for each mailitem
     nrt = Format(rt, "M/ d/ yyyy") 'formatting the received time to match value of datevalue keyword
     If DateValue(nrt) = Empty Then
        NonTicket0 = NonTicket0 + 1
     ElseIf DateValue(Date - 1) = DateValue(nrt) Then
        NonTicket1 = NonTicket1 + 1
     ElseIf DateValue(Date - 2) = DateValue(nrt) Then
        NonTicket2 = NonTicket2 + 1
     ElseIf DateValue(Date - 3) = DateValue(nrt) Then
        NonTicket3 = NonTicket3 + 1
     ElseIf DateValue(Date - 4) = DateValue(nrt) Then
        Exit For
     End If
NEXT ' <--- Add this
```